# AWS auto scaling single node groups?

Tags: aws-auto-scaling

Ok, I have a strange situation.  Can't find anything quite like it online.

Within a platform that I'm helping run, we have a couple of services that really can only run on a single node. Yes, our developers are working on fixing this, but in the meantime...  We are currently using HA to handle failover to a hot standby, but we would like to try to use AWS Auto Scaling Groups, for consistency in our architecture.

We've tried setting the min/max/des to 1/1/1, with some success.  However, we've had an issue arise where it takes about 3 minutes for the ASG to spin down a failed EC2, and spin up a replacement.  During this time, havoc ensues within the platform.

My question is this, is there a way to make the ASG start the new EC2 instance, before stopping the unhealthy one?

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions. This question is really about HA architecture in AWS. Probably best to look for a more appropriate forum..

Answer (score 0):

From my current knowledge, the answer is no.

The ASG schedule almost immediately the replacement instance. Unfortunately, the instance needs some time to warm up and pass the health check.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/healthcheck.html